# Start and Stop specific Job in Quartz Schedular Job when there are multi jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I am using Quartz Library to execute some tasks in my project, I need to execute multiple tasks so I am using multi scheular Jobs

The problem is that the job is stoped while the code is running because the code use API to get some data and sometime the code is hanging and the thread or job is stopped, So I need to restart the job agian when it stoped by hanging because of the server I get data from it by API

I try this code:

```
IJobDetail firstJob = JobBuilder.Create<FirstJob>()
           .WithIdentity("firstJob")
           .Build();

ITrigger firstTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
             .WithIdentity("firstTrigger")
             .StartNow()
             .WithCronSchedule("0 * 8-22 * * ?")
             .Build();


IJobDetail secondJob = JobBuilder.Create<SecondJob>()
           .WithIdentity("secondJob")
           .Build();

ITrigger secondTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
             .WithIdentity("secondTrigger")
             .StartNow()
             .WithCronSchedule("0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *")
             .Build();

Scheduler.ScheduleJob(firstJob, firstTrigger);
Scheduler.ScheduleJob(secondJob, secondTrigger);
```

But when I try to start or stop, all jobs start and all jobs stop:

```
Scheduler.Start();
Scheduler.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 : Add a misfire policy to the configuration. This will auto start a job which could not complete normally. See [this](https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire). This will only happen if you are using a DB based job store (Example, JDBC Jobstore) .It will not happen with RAM job store. Better is to use JDBC job store.

Approach 2 : Instead of starting and stopping the entire scheduler, start the specific job/stop the specific job. You can do this by using the unique job name.

Lastly, add logic to the place where you are calling the slow API to wait for several seconds for response. By doing this, the job will not get ended abruptly due to timeout exception.